# Building an Android multidex application using gradle without Android Studio (on a build server)

Tags: java, android, teamcity, android-multidex

I'm in the process of setting up a CI server running TeamCity.

The server is running openjdk8, I'm using build tools 23.0.2

I have a multidex Android app that I am able to build locally using assembleMyFlavorRelease. This same build fails on my TeamCity agent on `app:transformClassesWithDexForMyFlavorRelease`

The stacktrace shows `java` exiting with 1 though I can't seem to find why

```
[Gradle failure report] Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForMyFlavorRelease'.
[Gradle failure report] >
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Exception is:
[Gradle failure report] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForMyFlavorRelease'.
....
Caused by: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
....
Caused by: 
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

My app.gradle looks like this

```
productFlavors {

    final def MIN_SDK = 19
    final def TARGET_SDK = 23

    myFlavor {
        minSdkVersion MIN_SDK
        targetSdkVersion TARGET_SDK
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

With these dex options

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries false
 }
```

Compiling with

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
```

using multidex 1.0.1

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

The build agent completes both

```
:app:collectMyFlavorReleaseMultiDexComponents
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForMyFlavorRelease
```

Before failing on

```
app:transformClassesWithDexForMyFlavorRelease
```

Running with info reveals this before exiting

```
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException:
org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForMyFlavor'.] 
from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=2200, 
address=[a10b64d0-94c0-40e9-8b5d-b5a5bbb171c4 port:46291, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /127.0.0.1]], idle=false,
context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=968a9ee5-e6d4-4cba-a2a5-ce768ecbfe44,
javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64,
daemonRegistryDir=/root/.gradle/daemon,pid=2200,idleTimeout=120000,
daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx2048m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,
-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
```

Any help or direction at this point would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "The stacktrace shows java exiting with 1 though I can't seem to find why" -- are you sure there's nothing before this portion of the output?

Comment: Yup, all I see is before the stacktrace FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: If you have not done so already, try a regular command-line Gradle build (e.g., `gradle assembleDebug`). Try it on the Android Studio-equipped machine and on the TeamCity server. If they both succeed, probably the problem is tied to the TeamCity integration. If they both fail, probably the problem is tied to the Gradle build files. If the developer machine succeeds but the TeamCity server fails, the problem is probably related to something else in the environment (e.g., JDK version).

Comment: Ran `assembleDebug` both locally and on the build server, it works fine locally but fails on the server. I updated the post with info log output. Build server is running OpenJDK1.8 where I'm running `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a resource issue, I was running my builds on an AWS AMI without no swap and the dexer was running out of ram. It also didn't help that I was setting `javaMaxHeapSize` to `4g` on an AMI with only `2g` of ram.

To fix this I first reduced the `javaMaxHeapSize` to `2g`

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    preDexLibraries false
}
```

2g seems to be enough mempry for the dexing to avoid throwing a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` in my build. My project includes the Google Analytics library and had issues building with the default dex heap size.

On the AMI side I created a 2G swapfile, I'm running builds on an ubuntu AMI running on a T2.Small.

On my AMI:

```
sudo fallocate -l 2G /swap
sudo mkswap /swap
sudo swapon /swap
```

To persist after a reboot I added the following line to `/etc/fstab`

```
/swap    none    swap    sw    0    0
```

After this my T2 is now able to build without running into any errors.

Hope this helps someone